# "Deposit" vs "down payment" vs "advance (payment)"

Tags: differences

What is the difference? What context would I use them in? My native language only uses a single translation for all of these, afaik.

Comment: Please include information on what you want to say and provide examples.

Comment: This question may be migrated to the [Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange](http://money.stackexchange.com/), but have you tried learning from Wikipedia? [Down payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_payment) • [Advance payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_payment) • [Deposit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposit_(finance))

Comment: I can't believe your native language has no such distinctions ! Even in Kazakhstan I bet Borat got them :)

Comment: @Kyle : I don't think this question should be remove elsewhere because whe often have it even from natives. So I guess it's a question of plain vocabulary for everyone.

Comment: @DAVE Yeah. Vocabulary questions can fit on both websites.

Comment: @DAVE : Just because you don't have a separate word for it doesn't mean there's no distinction. It just depends on the context. However I think we do have a separate word for down payment after all.

Comment: @Paprik : I saw your were in CZ, so I'm sure you have different expressions. But take notice that if you don't have separate words you can't have real distinctions IN THIS word....

Answer (score 3):

1. A **deposit** is a **remittance** you do in advance, your $ are frozen on another account & you **loose all power of disposition on your money** but **you remain the owner** of this amount. The prupose of a deposit is to secure an operation.
2. A **down payment** is a fraction of the price you'd have to pay in advance ; if you finally don't make the transaction you get your money back ; which is not the case with *earnest money* (where you loose the sum if you don't complete the price).
3. An **advance payment** is simple : you simply *pay* in advance.

   The main difference btwn all these terms are a question of graduation & qualification but never implies wihtout other precision that in case the transaction doesn't go to its end the part who paid such sum has to loose it, except if it's *earnest money*. Ohter way, you should ask/have precision.
   And always bear in mind **a payment must have a counterpart** ; it's not a gift !